# Disabling Internet Curfew

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, proxy, wireless-router

So, my roommate was angry with me and put an internet curfew  of some kind on our router causing it to shut off at ten thirty and turn back on at eight. We have a D-Link DIR-815. I was wondering how I might disable the curfew? Thanks.

Comment: Reset the router then log in using the factory user name and password, then set a new password.....http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dir-815/reset-router.htm

Comment: Who pays the internet bill?

Answer (score 1):

Either

1. *You have the router password*: Browse to 192.168.0.1, enter it, and change the settings.
2. *You have physical access to the router*. Unplug it, press and *hold* the reset button, plug it back in. wait some 30 seconds, then let go of the reset button. The router will have lost *all* settings. Browse to 192.168.0.1, and set it up newly. Note that you might get in non-technical-related trouble later...

Comment: Where is the third option? Hit the roommate with a nurf bat until he reverses the changes?

Comment: or 4) Buy pizza & beer for roommate; man-hug & make up.